# Heroku: Can I commit remotely

Tags: heroku

We have a CMS on heroku, some files were generated by the CMS, how can I pull those changes down? Can I commit the changes remotely and pull them down? Is there an FTP option of some kind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem

It's not designed for persistent file generation and usage.

In practice, it works like this: User puts some code into a repository. That code is dynamically pulled into temporary Amazon EC instances and executed. The code can be pulled from virtual machine to virtual machine, node to node, without disruption, across data centers. There is no real "place" to get the products of your code from the environment, because anything generated by the checked-out code can (and will) be destroyed as your code deploy skips around between the temporary machines.

That being said, there are some workarounds:
If your app includes something like a file browser *within* your deployed code, you can grab the (entirely) temporary files using that file browser, and commit it back to your persistent code trunk.

Another option is using something like S3 for your persistent storage, with your application reading from, and writing to, a data storage service, knowing that while heroku will just re-write and destroy your local data on a frequent basis, the external service will maintain the files.

Similarly, you can change your application to use heroku's postgres for persistent data storage, or use Amazon's RDS, (etc.).

Alternately, you can edit your application in such a way as to ensure that any files generated by it will be regenerated every time the code is refreshed, redeployed, and moved around.

Comment: Interesting stuff Ron, thx for the rundown in layman's terms .. that would explain why I've seen some of those changes disappear, I guess it got automatically redeployed to another instance. I feel like there’s a great SaaS opportunity in here somewhere.